# Spark Structured Streaming - Spikes in Input rate, but processing rate still the same

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

I am running a Spark Structured Streaming job in Databricks. It has an Azure Eventhub as a source. When I look at the query graphs, I see the following:

[image]

There are big spikes in **Input rate** but the **Processing rate** is not really reacting to these spikes. But looking at the output results, it does not seem that some messages are being unprocessed/skipped.

Is there an explanation of such a behaviour?

**EDIT:** 
*Longer timeframe picture*
It can be seen that in low records-per-second range, the input rate and processing rate spikes together.. but according to the graph, Spark is not able to keep-up when the input processing spikes get too large.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check the graph again? It is only showing us the data of 23:03. Maybe your data is still processing and the orange curve spikes after 23.03 (depending on your processing logic)? Keep in mind that spark structured streaming processes incoming data in batches.

Comment: @cronoik EDIT - added longer time frame graph.

Comment: I have no clue of Azure, but can you turn off the eventhub without turning off the streaming application? In case that is possible, can you check how long it takes until spark stops processing records? I'm asking because I haven't found a ressource how they count processed records.